# async/await breaks when I add my own custom babelrc

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I wanted to customize my babelrc to have a few additional plugins. [Based on the 1.3.4 release notes](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v134), it totally looks like I could. So I made it like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-meteor"],
  "plugins": ["add-module-exports", "transform-class-properties"]
}
```

However, now whenever I attempt to use async/await, it completely breaks, saying that meteor code must run within a fiber.

```
Exception while invoking method 'add address' Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber.
```

This comes from a method that looks like this:

```
export async function addAddress() {
  await [whatever];
}
Meteor.methods({
  'add address': addAddress
});
```

If I completely remove the .babelrc, it appears to work.

Comment: You might need to wrap your async inside of ```Meteor.bindEnvironment()```, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: But the thing is, _without_ using a .babelrc, it works completely fine

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.

Apparently, you **cannot override meteor's native promise**, otherwise it breaks all the promises silently because meteor has it's own implementation.

```
import Bluebird from 'bluebird';
global.Promise = Bluebird;
```

Comment: Overriding the global may seem like a good idea, but it means the average dev looking at your code has no way of knowing what code relies on Bluebird and what core relies on standards, which means you easily end up with inconsistency.